# How can I accurately determine line of sight for a unit in Frozen Synapse?

Tags: frozen-synapse

Knowing the area visible to a unit and the area from which that unit is visible seems to be an essential part of the game.  The aim command shows a cone of possible coverage but that doesn't reflect what is *actually* visible to the unit.

Is there any way to determine what areas on the map are visible to a unit other than eye-balling it?

Comment: Related: [*How to determine shotgun range in Frozen Synapse?*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/31446/181240)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the hotkey 'v'.  Click on your unit, or even on one of his future waypoints, and hold the v key.  Move the mouse around, and you can see what his line of site is like, what he can shoot past, when he'll hit a wall, etc.

Comment: What's the difference between the dashed and slashed lines?