# How to determine shotgun range in Frozen Synapse?

Tags: frozen-synapse

Guessing wrong about whether or not a unit is within shotgun range has disastrous results.  Is there anything in the UI that shows you what weapons range is, maybe something like the line-of-sight `v` hotkey?

Comment: Why guess? That's why you run and re-run simulations before putting your turn in - to accurately *test* if something will work.

Comment: This is typically true, but you can't simulate engagement out past one turn.  There are times when it'd be good to know in advance if you can really hit that doorway from that cover _before_ you plan to move over there.

Comment: A quick web search shows up [this](http://fs.error420.com/wiki/Unit_Types), so apparently the range of a shotty is "16 tiles"... which doesn't help that much; how big is a tile?

Comment: Related: [*How can I accurately determine line of sight for a unit in Frozen Synapse?*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/23808/181240)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `v` line of sight hot key to work out if your shotgun unit is in range.

While holding the `v` key, you can move the mouse to a point to test if it is in range. If it is in range, the line from the selected point to the mouse pointer will be shown as a dashed line:

[image: Shotgun in range]

If the point is not in range, then the line will appear slightly wider with a diagonal pattern on it:

[image: Shotgun out of range]